# Shell scripting - running a regex to modify a file in place, that includes the file name

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I have many html files named 12345.html, 12346.html, etc.  I need to change "style.css" to "style-12345.css" or the appropriate file name.  I'm not sure what tool to use, recommendations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty easily done with a for loop and sed:

```
for i in *.html; do
    sed -i "s/style\\.css/style-`basename $i .html`.css/g" $i
done
```

The loop runs the inner command with `$i` set to each .html filename. `sed -i` modifies the file in place. `basename $i .html` gets `$i` without the `.html` suffix (i.e. just the number)

Comment: You should probably escape the '.' in the match section ("style.css" -> "style\.css") "just in case" ...

Comment: You should probably evaluate `\`basename $i .html\`` outside of the sed expression, in case you need it more then once.  I'd also recommend using `$()` instead of `\`\`` -- I find it easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

Look for a command named `rename`.  It comes in two varieties, depending upon the implementation.

The `perl` package provides `/usr/bin/prename` which uses perl-style regular expressions to rename files.  As an example, this command

```
$ prename 's/foo/bar/ *foo*
```

would change 'foo' to 'bar' in every filename that contains 'foo'.

The `util-linux` package provides `/usr/bin/rename` which uses simple string substitution to rename files.  As an example, this command

```
$ rename foo bar *foo*
```

would have the same effect as the first one.

`prename` is much more powerful than regular `rename`, but that power means it's trickier to use.

Comment: One of us is misunderstanding him; it sounded to me like he needs to change occurrences of "style.css" within the HTML files, not rename them. @wmil Some clarification might be in order

Comment: Or, he needs both tools, because he needs to rename a file, plus every reference to that file...

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -pi -e 's/style.css/style-12345.css/g' *.html
```